Tailwind grid columns not working as expected in 480px breakpoint
I am new to web development and I don't understand why the 'xs:max-md:grid-cols-1' is not working exactly as expected. I have already set the xs to be 480px in tailwind please help T_T
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/output.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/custom.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="login-container p-10 my-5 mx-auto w-4/5 bg-white rounded border border-black"
    >
      <h1 class="text-center font-bold text-4xl mb-5">Sign Up</h1>
      <form action="">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 text-black xs:max-md:grid-cols-1">
          <div class="w-full outline">
            <label for="fname" class=" ">First Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="fname"
              id="fname"
              class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="w-full">
            <label for="lname" class="">Last Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="lname"
              id="lname"
              class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="email" class="">Email (Institutional Email)</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
              class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="my-auto">
            <label for="password" class="">Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              id="password"
              class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="contact-number" class="">Contact Number</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="contact-number"
              id="contact-number"
              class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="student-id" class="">Student ID Number</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="student-id"
              id="student-id"
              class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <label for="course-program" class=""
              >Department and Course/Program</label
            >
            <select
              id="cars"
              name="cars"
              class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
            >
              <option value="it">Information Technology</option>
              <option value="cpt">Computer Technology</option>
              <option value="elx">Electronics Technology</option>
              <option value="ft">Food Technology</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="outline my-auto">
            <label for="year" class="">Year of Study</label>
            <select
              name="year"
              id="year"
              class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
            >
              <option value="1year">First Year</option>
              <option value="2year">Second Year</option>
              <option value="3year">Third Year</option>
              <option value="4year">Fourth Year</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-span-2">
            <label for="address" class="">Address</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="address"
              id="address"
              class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex justify-center">
          <button
            type="submit"
            class="mt-7 px-4 py-2 w-full bg-white text-black rounded border-black border"
          >
            Sign Up
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex justify-between text-sm">
          <div class="mt-4">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="terms-conditions"
              id="terms-conditions"
              class="mr-2"
            />
            <label for="terms-conditions" class=""
              >I agree to
              <a href="" class="underline text-blue-500"
                >Terms and Conditions</a
              ></label
            >
          </div>
          <div class="text-right">
            <p class="mt-4">
              Registered Already?
              <a href="" class="underline text-blue-500">Log In</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


I tried it to to make it a 1 column in the 480px or xs to sm breakpoint using grid-cols-1 but it only works on 1 column of the original

The col-span-2 on the wrapper of the address field causes the second grid column track to be created even when only one explicit column track is defined by the grid parent.
You could consider changing this to col-span-1 to match the breakpoint for grid-cols-1, like xs:max-md:col-span-1:


tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        xs: '480px',
      },
    },
  },
};
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div
  class="login-container p-10 my-5 mx-auto w-4/5 bg-white rounded border border-black"
>
  <h1 class="text-center font-bold text-4xl mb-5">Sign Up</h1>
  <form action="">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 text-black xs:max-md:grid-cols-1">
      <div class="w-full outline">
        <label for="fname" class=" ">First Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="fname"
          id="fname"
          class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="w-full">
        <label for="lname" class="">Last Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lname"
          id="lname"
          class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="email" class="">Email (Institutional Email)</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          id="email"
          class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="my-auto">
        <label for="password" class="">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          id="password"
          class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="contact-number" class="">Contact Number</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="contact-number"
          id="contact-number"
          class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="student-id" class="">Student ID Number</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="student-id"
          id="student-id"
          class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <label for="course-program" class=""
          >Department and Course/Program</label
        >
        <select
          id="cars"
          name="cars"
          class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
        >
          <option value="it">Information Technology</option>
          <option value="cpt">Computer Technology</option>
          <option value="elx">Electronics Technology</option>
          <option value="ft">Food Technology</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="outline my-auto">
        <label for="year" class="">Year of Study</label>
        <select
          name="year"
          id="year"
          class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
        >
          <option value="1year">First Year</option>
          <option value="2year">Second Year</option>
          <option value="3year">Third Year</option>
          <option value="4year">Fourth Year</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-2 xs:max-md:col-span-1">
        <label for="address" class="">Address</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="address"
          id="address"
          class="w-full rounded border-black bg-transparent border focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-center">
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="mt-7 px-4 py-2 w-full bg-white text-black rounded border-black border"
      >
        Sign Up
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-between text-sm">
      <div class="mt-4">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="terms-conditions"
          id="terms-conditions"
          class="mr-2"
        />
        <label for="terms-conditions" class=""
          >I agree to
          <a href="" class="underline text-blue-500"
            >Terms and Conditions</a
          ></label
        >
      </div>
      <div class="text-right">
        <p class="mt-4">
          Registered Already?
          <a href="" class="underline text-blue-500">Log In</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>




It worked! Thanks a lot :D
